# How to track activity of users/groups?

Tags: linux, users, user-groups

The only user in my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) is myself, but `/etc/passwd` contains **42** users and `/etc/group` contain **70** groups!!!
How could I find if such large number of users and groups are needed at all or not?

How could I know if any program is being used by one of these users/groups or not?

When was the last time that one of these users/groups were used?

Answer (score 0):

Use `last` to list login activity for users.

It is quite normal for packages you install to create a user/group to run the process, and these will have shells like /usr/sbin/nologin or /bin/false

You can check on currently logged in users using the command `w`